# Android: Round corners for Spinner items

Tags: android, android-layout, rounded-corners, android-spinner

I created an Android "Spinner" element like this:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/choice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_span="2"
    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:text="Choice"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"  />
```

The cell_shape.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#99CC3300"/>
    <corners android:radius="10px"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" /> 
</shape>
```

I create a "custom_spinner.xml" file for displaying the "Spinner-Elements" with rounded corners:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
    android:textColor="#988767" >
</TextView>
```

To display the "Spinner-Element" I use following code:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) table.findViewById(R.id.choice);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.planets_array, R.layout.custom_spinner);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The problem is now that the element items of the spinner have also square corners. It seems that only the "TextView" has rounded corners but not the spinner elements themselves.

Whats wrong here? Did I just use the wrong element type?

Regards

Comment: try to set the background of your `<Spinner>` to transparent using `android:background="#0000"`

Comment: @SherifelKhatib Hmm. Did not work :(.

Comment: Maybe you should add also android:popupBackground="#0000"

Answer (score 3):

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) table.findViewById(R.id.choice);
spinner.setAdapter(new MyCustomSpinnerAdapter(SearchScreen.this, R.layout.custom_dropDown_spinner, List));
```

Layout: custom_dropDown_spinner

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/title" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:textColor="#988767" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java Code:-

```
private class MyCustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList> {
        private ArrayList<String> objectsList = new ArrayList<String>();

        public MyCustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            this.objectsList = objects;
            // System.out.println("mak" + objectsList.size());
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
              //view show after click spinner
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView1(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dropDown_spinner, parent,
                    false);
            LinearLayout rowTitle = (LinearLayout) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.title);
                          rowTitle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);

            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.custom_spinner);

            textView.setText(objectsList.get(position).toString().trim());
            return rowView;
        }

        public View getCustomView1(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dropDown_spinner, parent,
                    false);
            LinearLayout rowTitle = (LinearLayout) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.title);



            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.custom_spinner);
            textView.setText(objectsList.get(position).toString().trim());
            textView.setTypeface(typeFace);
            // System.out.println("position " + position);
            return rowView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In getCustomView, you inflate custom_dropDown_spinner, but custom_dropDown_spinner does not have an R.id.row. Shouldn't this be R.id.title?

In getCustomView1, you inflate spinner_dropdown, but you never posted this in your example, nor is the inflated rowTitle ever used.

Comment: sorry & thanks  Corey.I have mistake in updating code.I think edited code will helpful for you.